# Is this CSS valid?

Tags: css

Is this CSS code valid? If not, how will it affect the rest of the page?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .detpage .fieldarea-row { position: static;!important;}
</style>
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon before the `!important` and it's good.

Comment: The usual way to answer that and learn is to put it in the file, referesh the page in question (in multiple browsers) and see for yourself.

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: CSS validation service: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: That link will be super helpful! Thanks! The code isn't on a page I own, but someone sent it to me for confirmation. I've never used it in that way before, so I wanted to make sure this wasn't just some exception I don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 1 semicolon too much. But shouldn't impact the rest.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .detpage .fieldarea-row { position: static !important;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not valid. your `!important` is just dangling there because youv'e "closed" the declaration early:

```
.detpage .fieldarea-row {
   position: static !important;
                   ^---- no ;
}
```

as for what it'll do. no way to tell. css just gives some rules to change layout/looks when things match, but you've provided nothing to show what this rule would apply to.

Comment: "as for what it'll do. no way to tell. css just gives some rules to change layout/looks when things match" Uh, [no](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors).

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this

```
.detpage .fieldarea-row { position: static !important; }
```

and put the style in a separate CSS file, to avoid mixing CSS with HTML codes.

Answer (score 0):

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator says that it's invalid, and that therefore the entire statement is invalid/ignored.

I'm not sure whether it's true though that the whole statement will be ignored (because that contradicts my understanding of CSS error recovery specification).